# window Task scheduler not giving option to run every 4 hours on daily

Tags: windows-7

I want to run a daily task scheduler daily and repeat every 4 hours.

I am getting the option to repeat max for 1 hour only. Can someone help here why I am not getting the option to run it every 4 hours?

Answer (score 0):

Although the longest default repeat duration is 1 hour, you can set task to repeat every number of hours you want, corresponding drop down menu just present you with 1 hour option to select, but you can type in any number of hours you need (see screenshot below).

[image]